# vlookup with several conditions

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

i would like to check if a a vlookup is ok of if this does not found nothing
i tried with the next formula

```
  =IF(B6="","",IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(B6,D:D,1,0)<>"Not found","Found"),"Not found"))
```

but it does not works, is easy i would like that this formula tell me if the value is here with "Found" and if the value is not here with "not found", as well if the cell where i need to put the value for find with vlookup is empty, this formula does not shows anything, looks like that im very close to do it :)

Comment: `=IF(LEN(B6),IF(MATCH(B6,D:D,0),"Found","Not Found"),"")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
`=IF(B6="","",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B6,D:D,1,0)),"Not found","Found"))` 
I tested it and it seems to do the trick